# How to Find & Replace a string in sql phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql

We have a lot of rows that contains like this below sentence in phpmyadmin SQL database:

```
a:2:{i:0;a:19:{s:41:s:3:"s:85:"http://link.com/abcd-123.html";s:0:"";s:5:"56";s:0:"";}}
```

We want to find where in this rows Starts with http://link.com/ and Ends with 123.html then remove anything before and after this and update into that row.
We can Find this links by this like in sql , But We don't know how to remove before and after that! :

```
"%http://link.com/%123.html%"
```

**Example :**
This :

```
    a:2:{i:0;a:19:{s:41:s:3:"s:85:"http://link.com/abcd-123.html";s:0:"";s:5:"56";s:0:"";}}
```

should be convert to this in every row (**Note! : "abcd-" is different in every row and only first and end of this link is similar**):

```
http://link.com/abcd-123.html
```

Thanks For Your Help

Comment: This is not easily done in SQL, you'll need to get some program involved. MariaDB 10.1 does regex-based search and replace, if you're using that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to do this using MySQL's base string functions.  If there is only a single URL, and you just want to extract it from that JSON data, then you can try the following:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(col,
                 INSTR(col, 'http'),
                 INSTR(col, 'html') - INSTR(col, 'http') + 4) AS url
FROM yourTable
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Thank You Very Much That Works!